# My project keeps referring to old files, Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have an app project I am building using the Cordova Library and Eclipse software. I changed my files including the App Name under my Icon and pushed it out to Google Play. For some reason, it keeps referring to my old App Name and other files even though the ones in my folder are the newest ones. I have cleaned my project and am seeing no errors. Is there something I can do to erase my history or why is it doing this? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: where did you change the app name?

Comment: I changed it in my androidmanifest.xml file in applications (Label), and also double-checked my actual androidmanifest file in my folders and it has been changed.

Comment: Which old app name? which files? you changed it in the strings? or do you mean package name? did you try manually deleting the output folder?

Comment: I refactored the package name so that should be alright. But I changed the androidmanifest.xml file (in eclipse there is a label for the field) and I also checked the actual file and it was changed. What is the output folder? I should try deleting that -- can you explain further?